# reference image won't show

Tags: image

I was using image references to create a character however after pressing some keys on my keyboard, which activated a short cut, when i attempted to go into front view to see my reference u=image, it appeared to have disappeared. As i was following a tutorial and therefore was doing it as a learning exercise i was willing to restart the project again, i started a new file. However once i re entered the reference images it still would not appear on my front view (I did set the axis' correctly)

If anyone knows of anything that could help that would be most appreciated, 
Thank you,
Nura

Comment: If it disappeared after you entered another preset orthographic view then it means you set up axes incorrect (in background image options).

Answer (score 1):

## Background images will only be displayed in:

1. Camera Prespective view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)
2. Any of the **preset** Orthographic views:

   Front/Back (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>)

   Right /Left (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>)

   Top/Bottom (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>)

To toggle between Prespective and orthogonal view use <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>